# How to create a table output from individual inputs?

Tags: tables, lists, latex3

I'm trying to generate a list of the author's orcid number from individual orcid numbers. Each orcid number of an author is given by the `\orcid` command in `\author`. However, I couldn't find enough information from google search. My MWE is as follows;

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Any configuration that should be done before the end of the preamble:
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,footskip=1cm,includehead,includefoot,columnsep=6mm,showframe}

\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\renewcommand\Authands{ and }
\newcommand{\abstractText}{\noindent\lipsum[8]}

\makeatletter
\newbox{\orcidbox}
\sbox{\orcidbox}{\includegraphics[width=4mm]{orcidid.png}}
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{%
    \href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\usebox{\orcidbox}}
    %
    % add item to list enviroment   <------------------------
}

\newcommand{\listoforcids}{
    \vspace*{5mm}
    \noindent\bfseries{\large List of Author orcids}
    %
    % create a tabular list from \orcid items    <------------------------
    \normalfont
    \par
    \hfil$\vdots$\hfil\par
    \hfil$\vdots$\hfil
}
\makeatother
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Configuration %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Article Title}

\author[1]{Author A \orcid{0000-000X-AAAA-BBBB}}
\author[2]{Author B \orcid{0000-000X-AAAA-CCCC}}
\author[2]{Author C \orcid{0000-000X-AAAA-DDDD}}
\affil[1]{Department of Computer Science}
\affil[2]{Department of Mechanical Engineering}

\begin{document}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Abstract %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            \abstractText
            \newline
            \newline
        \end{abstract}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    ]
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%
    % Article %
    %%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \section{Section Title 1}
    This is the first sentence\cite{ref1}.
    
    \section{Section Title 2}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque\footnote{First footnote}. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat\cite{ref2}. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus\cite{ref3}. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum\footnote{Second footnote}.
    
    \section{Section Title 3}
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \subsection{Section Title 3.1}
    \lipsum[3]
    
    \section{Section Title 4}
    \lipsum[4-5]
    
    
    \listoforcids
    
    \par\vspace*{3cm}
    \noindent expected output from \verb'\listoforcids' command
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            Author A & https://orcid.org/0000-000X-AAAA-BBBB\\
            Author B & https://orcid.org/0000-000X-AAAA-CCCC\\
            Author C & https://orcid.org/0000-000X-AAAA-DDDD\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
        
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % References %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \begin{thebibliography}{99}
        \bibitem[Ref1, (2003)]{ref1} Ref1 journal, 2003
        \bibitem[Ref2, (2006)]{ref2} Ref2 journal, 2006
        \bibitem[Ref3, (2009)]{ref3} Ref3 journal, 2009
    \end{thebibliography}   
\end{document}
```

How can we add each author name and orcid number to a list by using `\orcid` command? and How can we generate a table by using `\listoforcids` command? The expected output is shown as an example before References. Thanks to everyone who showed a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT 1: added code for the author declarations of the `mnras` class.**

**EDIT 2: Eliminate extra space in liost of orcids**

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% Any configuration that should be done before the end of the preamble:
\usepackage[super,comma,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue, citecolor=blue}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=1cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,footskip=1cm,includehead,includefoot,columnsep=6mm,showframe}

\usepackage{abstract}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand{\abstractnamefont}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\abstracttextfont}{\normalfont\small}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\renewcommand\Authands{ and }
\newcommand{\abstractText}{\noindent\lipsum[8]}

\newbox{\orcidbox}
\sbox{\orcidbox}{\includegraphics[width=4mm]{orcidid.png}}
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{%
    \href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\usebox{\orcidbox}}%
    %
    % add item to list enviroment   <------------------------
}

%% Generate List of Author orcids
\usepackage{xpatch}
\newcommand{\AuthorOrcidList}{}
\newcommand{\innerorcid}[1]{& https://orcid.org/#1}
\xapptocmd{\author}{{\let\orcid\innerorcid
                    \xappto{\AuthorOrcidList}{#2\\}}}{}{\FAIL}

\newcommand{\listoforcids}{
%    \vspace*{5mm}
    \section*{List of Author orcids}
    %
    % create a tabular list from \orcid items    <------------------------
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}% <<<< EDIT 2
      \AuthorOrcidList
    \end{tabular}
  }
%% End generate List of Author orcids

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Configuration %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{Article Title}

\author[1]{Author A \orcid{0000-000X-AAAA-BBBB}}
\author[2]{Author B \orcid{0000-000X-AAAA-CCCC}}
\author[2]{Author C \orcid{0000-000X-AAAA-DDDD}}
\affil[1]{Department of Computer Science}
\affil[2]{Department of Mechanical Engineering}

\begin{document}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%
    % Abstract %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \twocolumn[
    \begin{@twocolumnfalse}
        \maketitle
        \begin{abstract}
            \abstractText
            \newline
            \newline
        \end{abstract}
    \end{@twocolumnfalse}
    ]
    
    %%%%%%%%%%%
    % Article %
    %%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \section{Section Title 1}
    This is the first sentence\cite{ref1}.
    
    \section{Section Title 2}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue eu neque\footnote{First footnote}. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat\cite{ref2}. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus\cite{ref3}. Duis nibh mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim rutrum\footnote{Second footnote}.
    
    \section{Section Title 3}
    \lipsum[2]
    
    \subsection{Section Title 3.1}
    \lipsum[3]
    
    \section{Section Title 4}
    \lipsum[4-5]
    
    
    \listoforcids
    
    \par\vspace*{3cm}
    \noindent expected output from \verb'\listoforcids' command
    \begin{table}[!h]
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
            Author A & https://orcid.org/0000-000X-AAAA-BBBB\\
            Author B & https://orcid.org/0000-000X-AAAA-CCCC\\
            Author C & https://orcid.org/0000-000X-AAAA-DDDD\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
        
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    % References %
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    
    \begin{thebibliography}{99}
        \bibitem[Ref1, (2003)]{ref1} Ref1 journal, 2003
        \bibitem[Ref2, (2006)]{ref2} Ref2 journal, 2006
        \bibitem[Ref3, (2009)]{ref3} Ref3 journal, 2009
    \end{thebibliography}   
\end{document}
```

**Here is the code for the `mnras` documentclass. It is assumed that the `authblk` package is not used, i.e. the definition of `\author` is the one from `mnras.cls`.**

```
%% Generate List of Author orcids
\newcommand{\AuthorOrcidList}{}
\newcommand{\innerorcid}[1]{& https://orcid.org/#1\\}

% \author saves the authors in \@author, but \maketitle clears it
% So we save \@author at the beginning of \maketitle
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\maketitle}{\global\let\AuthorOrcidList\@author}{}{\FAIL}
\makeatother

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_authors_tl

\newcommand\splitauthors{
  \tl_set:NV \l_authors_tl \AuthorOrcidList
  % Remove all commas, superscripts, the word 'and' and the part starting with \\
  \regex_replace_all:nnN {,|\$.*?\$|\band\b|\c{\\}.*} {}  \l_authors_tl
  \tl_use:N \l_authors_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\listoforcids}{
    \section*{List of Author orcids}
    %
    % create a tabular list from \orcid items    <------------------------
    {\let\orcid\innerorcid
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}% <<<<<< EDIT 2
      \splitauthors
    \end{tabular}}
  }
%% End generate List of Author orcids
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @PietervanOostrum, your solution is awesome. Nothing to say to a pinpoint answer anymore.

Comment: Dear @PietervanOostrum, if we have an ```\author``` command like in the mnras.cls  ```\author[A Auth., B Auth. and C Auth.]{Author A,$^{1}$\corcid{0000-000X-AAAA-BBBB} Author B,$^{2}$\orcid{0000-000X-AAAA-CCCC} and, Author C$^{3}$\orcid{0000-000X-AAAA-DDDD} \\ $^1$Department of Computer Science\\ $^2$Department of Mechanical Engineering}```. How can we generate this orcid list? Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: That would be much more difficult. The author list would have to be split, the superscripts and commas removed, and the `and` removed. So it would be necessary to parse the whole thing which isn't trivial in LaTeX.

Comment: Maybe it can be done step by step. As a first step, how can we catch the first curved brackets gruop and split it with the name ```Author```?

Comment: In a real case there wouldn't be "Author", but rather something like "John T. Smith". Splitting on `\orcid` would seem more appropriate.

Comment: is it possible for you to show an example?

Comment: I have aded code for the `mnras` class (and it should probably work for any class that uses a similar `\author` definition).

Comment: Dear @PietervanOostrum, your solution is awesome again. Thank you very much.

Comment: Dear @PietervanOostrum, when I complied my tex file, there is extra one character space at beginning of first author in the list of orcids. What can be done for this?

Comment: Change the `tabular` to `\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}`.
By the way, you may also put a `%` after `\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\usebox{\orcidbox}}` to eliminate a space between the `orcidid` icon and the superscript.